# developing photo quiz app in eclipse

Tags: android

I am a beginner in eclipse. I need to create a photo quiz with at least 10 questions. I know how to use *ImageView*, *ImageButton* and *intent*. But I'm not getting a clear picture of how I should start. Do I have to create different xml files for each photo question? TQ for help

Comment: are you android beginner or not????

Comment: You can create just one xml, and just change the image and text when the user answer the question

Answer (score 0):

The Android guides are good for getting started, but I can appreciate there's quite a lot to read through if you want to hit the ground running.

A good starting point would be to get a basic app up and running with a single `Activity`that contains a `ListView`. There's a tutorial that should help [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Once you have got that far, start reading up about adding an image in the `ListView` `Adapter` under the `getView()` method.

I would recommend afterwards that you [read through all of the Android training docs](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html?utm_content=bufferf56e9&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=google&utm_campaign=Buffer) as the above will only offer a "quick fix"